# Converting a dictionary map to a mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a dictionary:

```
queryParameters = {
    "email":None,
    "party_type":'BUYER',
    "mobile":'9953610508'
}
```

I need to convert this into a sql where query excluding the None values. For this dict it would be something like this

```
select id from tff_party where deleted_at is null and mobile=9953610508 and party_type='BUYER';
```

I have created a function but string concatenation seems a problem here.

```
for key in queryParameters.keys():
    if queryParameters[key] is not None:
        res = key + "=" + queryParameters[key]
```

Comment: Writing fully dynamic and safe SQL queries is hard; you might want to consider using an ORM.  At least, understand how to inject values safely, as demonstrated in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/5320906).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.